# Baby born while converting

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, pregnancy-birth

Hello my girl friend is trying to convert the orthodox way and we are waiting for our appointment, but we just found out she is pregnant. What will happen now can she still convert the orthodox way, if the baby is born before she is done converting will it be considered Jewish, will we be able to take the baby to a orthodox temple to celebrate his or her birth. Please help me i am in a very hard situation, we didn't plan on the baby and we don't believe in an abortion and its past 40 days .